# How to start python unit tests from command line with Sikuli 1.0.1

Tags: python, unit-testing, sikuli

I have some tests, which were running from command line interface with -t parameter, which seems not to be supported with 1.0.1 any more.

The tests look like:

```py
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

class TestSeqFunc(unittest.TestCase):  

  def test1(self):
    click("a.png")
    assert True

  def test2(self):
    click("a.png")
    assert False

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSeqFunc)
outfile = open("/Users/vinogradov/Documents/Report.html", "w")
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile, title="Test Report", description="Test1")
runner.run(suite)
```

How could I start them, using Sikuli 1.0.1 (with Mac OS X, but the question is general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-service:

Just put HTMLTestRunner.py inside .sikuli package
then run with -r, not with -t:

In my case:

```
/Applications/SikuliX-IDE.app/Contents/runIDE -r test.sikuli
```

works perfectly!